# Where Project.json tools should go now?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm following [Entity Framework Core instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) step by step. At some point it says to

> locate the tools section and add the
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet package as shown below

`project.json`:

```
"tools": {
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
 },
```

As I understand, project.json is gone now. So where am I supposed to add this value? Project file?

Comment: Are you using VS2015 or VS2017RC? xporj or csproj ?

Comment: I'm using VS2017RC

Answer (score 6):

In the `project.json`/`xproj` format, it goes at the top-level in `project.json`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#tools

In the new `csproj` system, it's represented by `DotNetCliToolReference`. There's basically no documentation for this that I could find; I only found it by reading the source of `dotnet-migrate`.

An example of that looks like this:

```
<Project ...>
  <Import .../>
  <PropertyGroup .../>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

A more complete example of the output of `dotnet-migrate` is [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj).

Comment: But project.json is gone: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1433. Or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: Not yet. .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 both use `project.json` files for the moment. The `csproj` stuff is still in development and has rough edges. As a Microsoft developer says, [the next release will have (currently preview5) will have proper support](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1073#issuecomment-268673225).

Comment: Hm... I just created a .NET core class library in VS2017 and I don't see package.json file in it.

Comment: Ah. Visual Studio uses it's own thing. It's a variant of .NET Core 1.0 - not available anywhere else - except it uses csproj rather than project.json. I can't find anything about `tools` with Visual Studio :(

Comment: I read the source of `dotnet-migrate` and discovered `DotNetCliToolReference`. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in [Announcing Entity Framework Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/):

> If you are using the new .NET Core Tools MSBuild Alpha in Visual
>   Studio 2017 RC, the tooling story is more complicated. This is a point
>   in time issue and will be resolved as the .NET Core Tools MSBuild
>   support stabilizes.
>
> At this stage, you should use the Package Manager Console commands in
>   Visual Studio (Add-Migration, Update-Database, Scaffold-DbContext,
>   etc.). The .NET Core CLI commands (dotnet ef) do not currently work
>   with the .NET Core Tools MSBuild Alpha.

Long story short: it is not supported yet.